# Batch file equivalent in Linux

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, shell-script, batch-file

I have a few basic commands that I need to run on a Red Hat Linux 5 Virtual Machine with GNOME to start a couple servers.

**Example**

```
cd /home/user/scripts  
sh runTHISthing.sh pub  
cd /home/user/logs  
tailf pub.log
```

Not a crazy amount of code but sometimes I restart VM several times a day. In Windows, I would probably just create a batch file and put it on my desktop. Then it's just a matter of double clicking and off it goes.

Is there anyway to do the same in Linux? I've tried to create a launcher that just runs the emtpy file in terminal with no result.

Comment: You even got the right tag for this. It's called a shell script. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: @Mat I'm looking for a double click functionality. I want the file to sit on my desktop and I just double click, opens the terminal and runs the script. I know the a shell script is what I'm looking for, but I'm probably into hour 2 of my overall Linux experience and 30 minutes into Red Hat specifically. I did the research, it's just not working how I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In UNIX, a 'batchfile' is known as a shell script. A typical BASH shell script will start with a magic line that tells the operating system which shell to execute the script with, so your example would end up:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd /home/user/scripts   
 sh runTHISthing.sh pub   
 cd /home/user/logs  
 tailf pub.log
```

NOTE: After you create the file, you have to mark it as executable, in order for the OS to try executing it:

```
chmod +x myscript
```

Comment: Sorry, that last part about marking it executable. How would I do that?

Comment: In a terminal window, issue the command "chmod +x scriptfilename", with the correct path to your script.